# 1 dof parametrization of a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, linear-transformations

I found the following identity:

${\bf v}( \alpha ) = \cos(\alpha)\frac{{\bf x}+{\bf y}}{\| {\bf x}+{\bf y} \|}    + \sin(\alpha)\frac{{\bf x}\times{\bf y}}{\| {\bf x} \times {\bf y} \|}$ (1)

where  ${\bf v}( \alpha )$ is a 1dof parametrization of the rotation $R \in SO(3)$ such that ${\bf y}=R {\bf x}$ and $\times $ is the cross product. The corresponding rotation angle $\gamma $  for a given $\alpha$ can be found using

$\gamma =\arccos\left( \frac{{\bf p}_x^T {\bf p}_y }{\|{\bf p}_x\|\|{\bf p}_y\|} \right)$

where ${\bf p}_x={\bf x} -({\bf v}^T{\bf x}){\bf v}$ and  $p_y={\bf y} -({\bf v}^T{\bf y}){\bf v}$ are projections of the vector ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$ onto the plane whose normal is the rotation axis ${\bf v}$. The  rotation $R$ can be computed using the exponential map using ${\bf v}$ and $\gamma$.

How can I prove identity (1)?

Br,

Nicolas

Comment: So, it should be ${\bf p}_y={\bf y} -({\bf v}^T{\bf y}){\bf v}$ ?

Comment: Hi Cab,
Thank you for pointing out my typo.

Comment: Then, for a pure rotation without scaling, it shall be $
\frac{\mathbf{y}}
{{\left\| \mathbf{y} \right\|}} = R\frac{\mathbf{x}}
{{\left\| \mathbf{x} \right\|}}
$ , if I understood correctly your scheme

Comment: Yes Cab, it might be that this is an error in the input description. How would it affect the scheme if the vectors are not scaled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rotation, by definition, keeps the euclidean norm (length) of the vectors. To pass from 
$\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{y}$ you need in general a rotation and a scale factor.
$$ \frac{\mathbf{y}}
{{\left\| \mathbf{y} \right\|}} = R\;\frac{\mathbf{x}}
{{\left\| \mathbf{x} \right\|}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \mathbf{y} = \left( {\frac{{\left\| \mathbf{y} \right\|}}
{{\left\| \mathbf{x} \right\|}}} \right)R\;\mathbf{x} $$
Apart from that, your scheme is correct.  In fact, putting
$$ \mathbf{t} = \frac{{\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}}}
{{\left\| {\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}} \right\|}}\quad \mathbf{n} = \frac{{\mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y}}}
{{\left\| {\mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y}} \right\|}}\quad \mathbf{v}\left( \alpha  \right) = \cos \left( \alpha  \right)\mathbf{t} + \sin \left( \alpha  \right)\mathbf{n}
$$
we have that
$\mathbf{t} $ is a unit vector, co-planar with $\mathbf{x} $ and  $\mathbf{y} $;
$\mathbf{n} $ is the unit normal vector to the plane of $\mathbf{x}$ , $\mathbf{y}$;
$\mathbf{v}\left( \alpha  \right)$ is a unit vector, in the plane $\mathbf{t}$, $\mathbf{n}$.
Then the angle of rotation around $\mathbf{v}$ that brings $\mathbf{x} $ onto  $\mathbf{y} $
is the dihedral angle between the planes $\mathbf{x} $, $\mathbf{v}$  and $\mathbf{y} $, $\mathbf{v}$.
That can be computed in multiple ways.
One way is that you adopted of computing the components of $\mathbf{x} $ and $\mathbf{y} $
orthogonal to $\mathbf{v} $, and then taking the angle between them.
Another way would be to compute the angle between $ \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{y} \times \mathbf{v}$ (angle between the normals to the planes).
Finally note that if you apply your scheme starting with  $ \frac{\mathbf{x}}{{\left\| \mathbf{x} \right\|}} $ and $ \frac{\mathbf{y}}{{\left\| \mathbf{y} \right\|}} $, in place of 
$\mathbf{x} $ and $\mathbf{y} $, then these unit vectors will be symmetric with respect to the plane containing $\mathbf{t} $, $\mathbf{v} $,$\mathbf{n} $.

Comment: Hi Cab,

Thanks for clarifying the geometric structure of the rotation scheme. Unfortunately I still don't understand the introduction of the parametrization of ${\bf v}$ by the parameter $( \alpha )$. Do you have an idea what could be the purpose of this parameter? Is it not sufficient to compute the normal to ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$ and then compute the rotation angle?

nicolas

Comment: Yes, you can bring ${\bf x}$ to ${\bf y}$ by a rotation around the normal to their plane. Yet, in 3D, there are other rotations that give the same result, i.e. those that rotate ${\bf x}$ around a cone containing both ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$: $\alpha$ is the inclination of the axis of the cone with respect to the  ${\bf x}$, ${\bf y}$ plane. If you apply the scheme starting as suggested with $\frac{\mathbf{x}}{{\left\| \mathbf{x} \right\|}}$ and $\frac{\mathbf{y}}{{\left\| \mathbf{y} \right\|}}$, the whole will be more evident.

Comment: (cont'd) For instance you can see that for $\alpha=0$ you get a reflection of ${\bf x}$ onto ${\bf y}$ around their bisecting line.